# Replicate data across folders on-the-fly automatically in Mac OS X 10.10.4 (Yosemite‎)

Tags: macos, backup, sync, file-transfer

Long time Mac User running OS10.10.4.

I'm looking for the best method to replciate data across separate folders on-the-fly.

That is to say, I want to copy data to `Folder A` then have it *automatically duplicated* to `Folder B`, `Folder C`, and `Folder D`.

[image]

I realize I could use any number of back up tools or shareware to sync folders at some predetermined time. However, I want this to happen *upon change of Folder A* and only duplicate the *new* data, not the entire folder, so the data is backed up immediately in three separate locations.

I'm not opposed to software purchases, I already run things like [DejaVu](http://propagandaprod.com/) and [FolderSync](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/39495/folder-sync)... but these have to be set to a *specific* time of day or manually instigated. Not what I'm after. Time Machine just does the system... not what I'm after.

So far I've been unsuccessful at creating a Folder Action that will accomplish this. I can create folder actions that replicate an entire folder, but I just want the changed data to be replicated, not the entire folder. (Or perhaps I'm just not seeing the correct options for Folder Actions).

**So, how would one configure a Folder to replicates its *changed* data on-the-fly like this?**

Even setting Folder A as a "watched" folder, dropping data into it, then removing it from folder A after the duplications would work. Using Applescript to "watch" Folder A fails to a degree. There's a very *noticeable* cursor delay when the folder is "checked" which causes issues while trying to get work done. Reducing the period of checking to circumvent these delays defeats the purpose of using the script. That's why I was more after a folder action that only initiates upon the folder change than a continually running process to watch the folder.

Something like:

```
if (FolderACurrentCount > FolderAPastCount) {
   copy "newest item" from Folder A to Folder B;
   copy "newest item" from Folder A to Folder C;
   copy "newest item" from Folder A to Folder D;
}
```

(I'm just spitballing to try and explain).

I'm essentially looking for a better method than drag/dropping to 3 separate locations.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FolderSynchronizer](http://www.softobe.com/folderssynchronizer.html) which supports running an AppleScript after it executes.

So have it run an AppleScript which runs it again after a short interval, thus watching the folder.

Comment: The issue with Applescript is that it slows the system by constantly checking a folder. There's a very *noticeable* cursor delay when the folder is "checked" which causes issues while trying to get work done. Reducing the period of checking to circumvent these delays defeats the purpose of using the script. That's why I was more ofter a folder action that only initiated upon the folder change than a continually running process to watch the folder.